# Llamar función con 2 parámetros predeterminados en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, funciones

tengo una duda

El siguiente ejemplo no es el caso real, pero lo ejemplifica perfecto

```
function suma($numero1 = 7, $numero2 = 10){
   $suma = $numero1 + $numero2
   return $suma;
}
```

La cosa es que yo quisiera pasarle un parámetro a $numero2, pero dejar que $numero1 mantenga su valor por defecto. Algo así:

```
suma(numero2: 18);
```

Debería dar como resultado 25, porque el numero1 tiene el valor predeterminado 7, pero el numero2 ahora es 18.

No se si me di explicar, pero básicamente es llamar a una función con varias variables predeterminadas, y pasando un solo valor, poder especificarle a que parámetro va dirigido

Se que algo así seria en Javascript

```
suma({numero2: 18});
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería que tu función `suma()` reciba un arreglo asociativo, que le llamaremos `$params`. Dentro de la función, verificamos si los valores para `numero1` y `numero2` están presentes en el arreglo. Si no se proporciona un valor para `numero1`, se utiliza el valor predeterminado `7`, lo mismo para `numero2`, se utiliza el valor predeterminado `10`.

De esta forma puedes llamar a la función y modificar los valores desde el propio argumento. Si no se modifican sus valores, la función se encarga de tomar los valores por defecto.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function suma($params = array()) {
   // Si "numero1" tiene un valor asignado, $numero1 será ese mismo valor, de lo contrario, será 7.
   $numero1 = isset($params['numero1']) ? $params['numero1'] : 7;
   // Si "numero2" tiene un valor asignado, $numero2 será ese mismo valor, de lo contrario, será 10.
   $numero2 = isset($params['numero2']) ? $params['numero2'] : 10;
   
   $suma = $numero1 + $numero2;
   return $suma;
}

$resultado1 = suma(['numero1' => 5]); // Asigno el valor de "numero1" a 5 => 5 + 10 = 15
$resultado2 = suma(['numero2' => 5]); // Asigno el valor de "numero2" a 5 => 7 + 5 = 12
$resultado3 = suma(); // No asigno ningún valor, tomando la asignación de sus valores dentro de la función => 7 + 10 = 17

echo $resultado1 . '<br>'; // 15
echo $resultado2 . '<br>'; // 12
echo $resultado3; // 17
?>
```

Comment: Me imagino que no hay un forma de llamar a las funciones por el nombre de los parametros, como en JS. Pero, este código funciona perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Y que problema tienes con dejarlo "seteado" en la variable?

```
<?php
    function suma($numero2 = 10){
        $numero1 = 7;
        $suma = $numero1 + $numero2;
        return $suma;
    }

    echo 'La Suma es : '.suma();
    // La Suma es : 17
```

Pero esa no es la forma adecuada de trabajar con las funciones. Lo mejor es declararlas con los parámetros que necesitan y en la llamada asignar los valores de esos parámetros.

```
<?php
    function suma($numero2){
        $numero1 = 7;
        $suma = $numero1 + $numero2;
        return $suma;
    }

    echo 'La Suma es : '.suma($numero2 = 3);
    // La Suma es : 10
```

Y yo, antes asignaría el valor, así la llamada a mi función queda "mas limpia".

```
<?php
    function suma($numero2){
        $numero1 = 7;
        $suma = $numero1 + $numero2;
        return $suma;
    }

    $numero2 = 25;
    echo 'La Suma es : '.suma($numero2);
    // La Suma es : 32
```

Comment: Porque en otras llamadas a la función el número 1 se puede reemplazar y en otras es el número 2.

Comment: Entonces ninguno **MANTIENE POR DEFECTO SU VALOR** como tu lo dijiste en tu ejemplo. Al final no se como le hizo pero @Cris si te entendió :-p

Comment: Lo decía  refiriéndome a que el número 1 podía variar en ciertos casos, pero cuando no, dejarlo como se le había predefinido. Igual, gracias